# CGcontext origin after rotation

Tags: ios, image-processing, rotation, cgimage, ciimage

I am trying to rotate an image about the center then place the rotated image's center over a point. When I draw it on the context after rotatoin it does not draw where i expect...

```
CGContextTranslateCTM( context, xOffset, yOffset);
CGContextRotateCTM(context, radiansOffset);
CGContextTranslateCTM( context, -xOffset, -yOffset)

[backgroundimage drawInRect:CGRectMake( x, y, width, height)];
```

When i place the image without rotation, it is placed where i want, but after rotation as above, it is placed almost as if its still being rotated around a point outside of the image itself.

Comment: I figured out it is placing the image based on the rotated coordinate system which is different then the one the background image was using, is there a way to place the image without using the rotated coordinate system?

Comment: Have you figured it out?